# Why does tomcat replace context.xml on redeploy?

Tags: deployment, tomcat, tomcat6

Documentation says if you have a context file here:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
```

it will NOT be replaced by a context file here:

```
mywebapp.war/META-INF/context.xml
```

It is written here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

> Only if a context file does not exist for the application in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/, in an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application files.

But everytime I re-deploy the war it replaces this myapp.xml with the /META-INF/context.xml!

Why does it do it and how can I avoid it?

Thanx

Comment: Are you deploying manually or by an IDE plugin?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't put a context.xml on the app server.  I don't because I can seldom depend on having access to that file.  I usually keep it local to my WAR file.

Comment: I am deploying manually by putting mywebapp.war into $CATALINA_HOME/webapps. I keep my default settings in the WAR, but I want to be able to change those settings on a per-instance basis without modifying the war itself - that is why I want my context in the conf directory unchanged

Comment: See this recent chain on the mailing list http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg81854.html

Comment: and recently on SF as well http://serverfault.com/questions/192784/why-does-tomcat-like-deleting-my-context-xml-file/192810#192810

Comment: thank you, JoseK. I seem to get it now. Undeployment causes removal of the context file

Comment: It might be a bit late, but you can have a look at this question to see a possible way to get around this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142365/

Comment: This kind of questions should be up voted actually.

Answer (score 6):

Undeploy part of redeploy deletes app and the associated context.xml.

If you use maven tomcat plugin you can avoid deleting context.xml if you deploy your app with command like this:

```
mvn tomcat:deploy-only -Dmaven.tomcat.update=true
```

More info here: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html

You can use deploy-only with parameter mode to deploy the context.xml too.

Comment: For folks following along at home: `mvn tomcat7:deploy-only -Dmaven.tomcat.update=true -Dmaven.tomcat.mode=both -Dmaven.tomcat.contextFile=/foo/context.xml` does the trick. Sad... but effective in tomcat7.

Answer (score 5):

**The short answer:**

Just make the **TOMCATHOME/conf/Catalina/localhost** dir read-only, and keep reading for more details:

- For **quick deployment mode** (Eclipse dynamic web project, direct Tomcat
  connection, etc.) on a local/non-shared Tomcat server you can just define your JDBC datasource (or any
  other 'web resource') using the **META-INF/context.xml** file inside the
  WAR file. Easy and fast in your local environment, but not suitable for staging, QA, or
  production.
- For **build deployment mode** (usually for staging, QA, or prod), JDBC
  datasources and other 'web resources' details are defined by the
  QA/production team, not the development team anymore. Therefore, they
  must be specified in the Tomcat server, not inside the WAR file
  anymore. In this case, specify them in the file
  **TOMCATHOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/CONTEXT.xml** (change **Catalina**
  by the engine, and **localhost** by the host, and **CONTEXT** by your context accordingly). However,
  Tomcat will delete this file on each deployment. To prevent this
  deletion, just make this dir read-only; in Linux you can type:

  > ```
  >    chmod a-w TOMCATHOME/conf/Catalina/localhost
  > ```

  Voila! Your welcome.

**The long answer**

- For historical reasons Tomcat allows you to define web resources (JDBC datasources, and others) in four
  different places (read four different files) in a very specific order of precedence, if you happen to define the same resource multiple times. The ones named in the
  short answer above are the more suitable nowadays for each purpose, though you could still
  use the others (nah... you probably don't want to). I'm not going to
  discuss the other ones here unless someone asks for it.

Comment: This will not work when autodeploy is turned on for tomcat and you use tomcat7:undeploy it will complain that it cannot delete the Context Descriptor file

Comment: With this option, my deploys fail with the error message `Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset` for the reason mentioned in Chad's comment. Instead, I used the option using context.xml from WEB-INF and optional (external) jndi resource from server.xml as described in the first answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142365/how-to-provide-a-context-configuration-for-a-web-application-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

On tomcat7, also woth autoDeploy=false the file will be deleted on undeploy. This is documented and not a bug (althought it avoids good automated deployments with server-side fixed configuration).

I found a workaround which solved the problem for me:

- create a META-INF/context.xml file in your webapp that contains
- on the Server create a second context "/config-context" in server.xml and put all your server-side configuration parameters there
- on the application use context.getContext("/config-context").getInitParameter(...) to access the configuration there.

This allows a per-host configuration that is independent of the deployed war.

It should also be possible to add per-context configurations by adding contexts like "/config-context-MYPATH". In your app you can use the context path oth the app to calculate the context path of the config app.

Comment: Why are the core tomcat devs so ignorant of best practices deployment? I lost basically a night to get a workaround here and all the work arounds are anti-patterns, but the TC devs are in denial and won't acknowledge that this is a sensible approach to install JNDI properites and sources on the host, not compile them into the SCM and war. https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34840

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html#Deleted_files) upon redeploy tomcat detects the deletion (undeploy) of your application.  So it will start a cleanup process deleting the directory and xml also. This is independent of auto deployment - so it will happen upon redeployment through manager and  modification of war also. There are 3 exceptions:

- global resources are never deleted
- external resources are never deleted
- if the WAR or DIR has been modified then the XML file is only deleted
  if copyXML is true and deployXML is true

I don't know why, but copyXML="false" deployXML="false" won't help.

Secondly: Making the directory read only just makes tomcat throwing an exception and won't start.

You can try merging your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp-1.xml, $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp-2.xml, etc files into $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml (that works only if you make sure your application won't deploy its own context configuration, like myapp-1.xml)

If someone could tell what is that "external resources" that would generally solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The general issue as described by the title is covered by [Re-deploy from war without deleting context](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58935) which is still an open issue at this time.

There is an acknowledged distinction between re-deploy which does not delete the context, and deploy after un-deploy where the un-deploy deletes the context. The documentation was out of date, and the manager GUI still does not support re-deploy.

Answer (score -1):

Redeployment means two parts: undeployment and deployment.

Undeployment removes the `conf/Catalina/yourhost/yourapp.xml` because the

```
 <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" 

           autoDeploy="true">      <!-- means autoUndeploy too!!! -->

 </Host>
```

Change the `autoDeploy="false"` and Tomcat has **no order anymore** to remove the `conf/Catalina/yourhost/yourapp.xml`.

There is an feature that allowes us to make those steps (undeploy/deploy) as one single step (redeploy) that do not remove the `context.xml`. This feature is available via the manager-text-interface, but the option is not available using the manager-html-interface. You might have to wait until the [bug in tomcat](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58935) is fixed. You can use the method described in this answer as an workaround.

Comment: Undeployment deletes the context. Re-deployment must not delete the context because it has nothing to do with un-deploying the application logically because that is not the intention of the operation as reflected by the word. It is unfortunate that this distinction is not made clear. Simply speaking, Redeployment is a word with its own meaning.

Comment: @user250343 Changed answer, please check.