# Short url or alias for deployed application in tomcat 6

Tags: java, url, tomcat, short-url

I have a web application project which is deployed in tomcat 6. 
I can access my application using the url:

http://localhost:8082/MyApplication

I also wan't to be able to access this application by another url like:
      http://localhost:8082/myapp

Is this possible ? if yes what alternatives do i have ?

Off course, I don't want to change the original name of the application('MyApplication').

Thanks,
Abhishek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add the `Context` within `server.xml` it will work as you want. Give the `path` attribute you wish.

```
<Context docBase="MyApplication" path="/myapp" />
```

Though it works, this approach is not recommended by the Tomcat docs, since any changes to `server.xml` means restarting the server disturbing all the web apps.

But, on the flip side, the practice of keeping this in `Catalina_Home/conf/Catalina/localhost/context.xml` (which is recommended by the docs) has some unreliabilities as others have reported - when you redeploy the war you can lose the `context.xml` too

See [Why-does-tomcat-replace-context-xml-on-redeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032773/why-does-tomcat-replace-context-xml-on-redeploy) and 
[Why does tomcat like deleting my context.xml file?](https://serverfault.com/q/192784/37747)