# Context.xml file missing Tomcat 8

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web, context.xml

I'm a beginner at creating a dynamic web project in Eclipse. I need the `context.xml` file to set up a database realm, but it's not under `META-INF`, instead I have found it in Tomcat's conf directory. Have I configured Eclipse/Tomcat wrong since all sources says the file should be in `META-INF`? How can I add a `context.xml` file to my project?

I am using Eclipse mars and Tomcat 8.

**Edit**
I read the post linked in the comments, they are not duplicates. Frankly I cannot even understand what the other person is asking, though this could be due to all this terminology being new to me.

Comment: Please check.http://stackoverflow.com/a/7170898/1638718

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to provide a context configuration for a web application in Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142365/how-to-provide-a-context-configuration-for-a-web-application-in-tomcat)

Comment: That question, they already have a context.xml file under meta-inf.

Comment: Just create it, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Even though Eclipse is an awesome tool, I recommend you do the web things with NetBeans.

In Eclipse you might not find the `context.xml` file where it should be under `meta-inf`, to find the file you can check followings:

First check the workspace path in `Eclipse`, assume it points to `/root/workspace`.

Then explorer the folder, you should have a folder called `Servers`, if you don't simply try to find it by looking in server tab in Eclipse.

In the Servers folder, you will find something like `Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config`, locate the folder and the config files related to the tomcat will be found there.

This is because Eclipse follows its workspace schema for web-apps as well, while NetBeans follows the things specified by Tomcat.

And remember creating, editing or removing config files for tomcat while you are working with Eclipse will not affect anything since the files specified will be used instead.

---

The server stuffs would be found as a project-like item named `server` too, you can find it on package-manager where you explore the projects tree, stuffs,...